# Datetime conversion in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

It seems that I can't make `date_format` work. Using a format that I know work on my data (see below)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
dat.withColumn("ts", date_format(dat("timestamp"), "MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSS a (z)")).select("timestamp", "ts").first
```

I get

```
res310: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [Aug-11-2016 09:21:43:749 PM (CEST),null]
```

Reading the doc I understand that `date_format` should accept any `SimpleDateFormat`. Is that correct?

I can make it work going through the pain of the code below:

```
val timestamp_parser = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSS a (z)")
val udf_timestamp_string_to_long = udf[Long, String]( timestamp_parser.parse(_).getTime() )
val udf_timestamp_long_to_sql_timestamp = udf[Timestamp, Long]( new Timestamp(_) )
dat.withColumn("ts", udf_timestamp_long_to_sql_timestamp(udf_timestamp_string_to_long(dat("timestamp")))).select("timestamp", "ts").first
```

which gives

```
res314: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [Aug-11-2016 09:21:43:749 PM (CEST),2016-08-11 21:21:43.749]
```

Comment: I am not sure if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281152/spark-unix-timestamp-data-type-mismatch/39281631#39281631) can help at all...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to convert a string field into timestamp in Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844144/better-way-to-convert-a-string-field-into-timestamp-in-spark)

Comment: If you want to convert string to timestamp field you're using a wrong function. `date_format` is used to create formated string, not to parse dates.

Comment: @zero323 Hmmm that's embarrassing.

Comment: @CedricH. Happens to the best of us :)